# How can I provide the field to use in a function?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Something working on the likes of Linq's OrderBy, in which you can specify the key with which it is supposed to do the ordering.

To make things specific, in my case I have an equivalent of a struct with two bool properties, one .IsNice and another .IsPretty; I then want to be able to do a function returning wether an instance Is Pretty or Is Nice.

I could make two functions,

```
    bool itIsPretty (ExampleStruct toVerify);
    bool itIsNice (ExampleStruct toVerify);
```

both, however, are essentially the same thing! Both are nothing more than a return toVerify.(IsPretty / IsNice), and I do not want to have a copy and pasted function.

Another alternative would be making the following:

```
    bool isItNiceOrPretty (ExampleStruct toVerify, bool checkForNiceness)
    {
        if (checkForNiceness) return toVerify.IsNice;
        else return toVerify.IsPretty;
    }
```

But, what if there were more than these two types? Well, I could turn this bool parameter into an integer, or a string, but then I'd need to keep a table with all the key values and their respective fields... This has such a potential for mess and counter-intuitivity when I add and/or remove fields of the example struct that I don't even want to think any more about it.

So, is there a way to do what I'm thinking, to create such a flexible function? Or do I have to stick to the dreadful Ctrl+C Ctrl+V?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass in a `Func<ExampleStruct,bool>`:

```
bool DoSomething(ExampleStruct value, Func<ExampleStruct,bool> predicate)
{
    if (predicate(value))
    {
       // Do your thing
    }
}
```

You could then call this via:

```
bool result = DoSomething(toVerify, v => v.IsNice);
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an enumerator as your second parameter:

```
public enum CheckType
{
    Nice,
    Pretty,
    // And so on...
}

public Boolean IsWhat(ExampleStruct struct, CheckType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case CheckType.Pretty: 
           return toVerify.IsPretty;

         // And so on...
    }    
}
```

If you have different structures, you could implement a common interface:

```
public interface ILook
{
    Boolean IsNice { get; }
    Boolean IsPretty { get; }
}

public struct ExampleStructA : ILook { }

public Boolean IsWhat(ILook tiVerify, CheckType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case CheckType.Pretty: 
           return toVerify.IsPretty;

         // And so on...
    }    
}
```

Or you could use a generic function with a predicate.